# Higher order functions in Python using reduce technique

Tags: python

> For the below query, show that both summation and product are
>   instances of a more general function, called accumulate, with the
>   following signature:
>
> ```
> def accumulate(combiner, start, n, term):
>     """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```
>
> Accumulate takes as arguments the same arguments term and n as
>   summation and product, together with a combiner function (of two
>   arguments) that specifies how the current term is to be combined with
>   the accumulation of the preceding terms and a start value that
>   specifies what base value to use to start the accumulation. Implement
>   accumulate and show how summation and product can both be defined as
>   simple calls to accumulate:
>
> ```
> def summation_using_accumulate(n, term):
>     """An implementation of summation using accumulate.
>
>     >>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
>     30
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
>
> def product_using_accumulate(n, term):
>     """An implementation of product using accumulate.
>
>     >>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
>     576
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

Below is the solution:

```
    from operator import mul, add


def accumulate(combiner, start, n, f):
    """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""

    total = start           #Result of summation gets stored here
    i = 1                   #Initial value of sequence
    while i <= n:
        total = combiner(total, f(i))
        i = i + 1
    return total


def summation_using_accumulate(n, f):
    """An implementation of summation using accumulate.

    >>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
    30
    """
    return accumulate(add, 0, n, f)



def product_using_accumulate(n, f):
    """An implementation of product using accumulate.

    >>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
    576
    """
    return accumulate(mul, 1, n, f)


def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)

print("product_using_accumulate: ",product_using_accumulate(4, square))
print("summation_using_accumulate: ",summation_using_accumulate(4, square))
print(accumulate(add, 0, 4, square)) 
print(accumulate(mul, 1, 4, square))
```

I have tested this code and looks good to me.

My questions:

1. Does the solution look incorrect in any aspect?
2. Any feedback on naming conventions?
3. Any feedback on coding style?

Comment: Well for one thing, neither of your `..._using_accumulate` functions *actually use `accumulate`*! Your calls at the end should be inside those functions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe wrt your point `neither of your ..._using_accumulate functions actually use accumulate! ` , i still did not understand, where is this point asked in the query? Please help me!!

Comment: Per the specification *"show how summation and product can both be defined as simple calls to accumulate"* - your implementations **do not call `accumulate`**. And in terms of *"feedback on Coding style"* - see [the style guide](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: @jonrsharpe ya you are right!! Now i understood the meaning of 'can both be defined'

Comment: @jonrsharpe for this point, `can both be defined as simple calls to accumulate` it could also mean that replace two definitions by one which is accumulate(), Otherwise if we call accumulate from summation & product then we did not reduce the code.

Comment: Why do you think the functions are named `..._using_accumulate`?! The purpose is not just to minimise the code (Python has `sum` and `reduce` built right in, so why bother with any of this?), it's to understand the processes involved.

Comment: @jonrsharpe DO you think the solution looks fine now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the implementation I think you were being led towards:

```
##from functools import reduce # if Python 3.x
from operator import add, mul

def accumulate(combiner, start, n, f):
    """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
##    return reduce(combiner, (f(i+1) for i in range(n)), start) # <- built-in version
    total = start
    for i in range(n):
        total = combiner(total, f(i+1))
    return total 

def summation_using_accumulate(n, f):
    """An implementation of summation using accumulate.

    >>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
    30
    """
    return accumulate(add, 0, n, f)

def product_using_accumulate(n, f):
    """An implementation of product using accumulate.

    >>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
    576
    """
    return accumulate(mul, 1, n, f)

def square(x):
    return mul(x, x)
```

That's how you can

> show how summation and product can both be defined as simple calls to accumulate

i.e. simply **by doing it**, which gives the results required:

```
>>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
576
>>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
30
```

Also, note the use of `for` and `range`, which is easier and much less error-prone that manually incrementing values in a `while` loop.

So the answers to your specific questions:

1. No; `accumulate`, `product_using_accumulate` and `summation_using_accumulate` were all wrong, but you've fixed that now;
2. No; not now that you've removed `Currentterm` (which should have been `current_term` - per the style guide, variable names are `lowercase_with_underscores`); and
3. Yes; you need more spaces, e.g. `return accumulate(add,0,n,f)` should be `return accumulate(add, 0, n, f)`.

Comment: I think `for i in range(1, n + 1)` would be better: less risk of accidentally writing `i` in the loop body instead of `i + 1`.

Comment: @GarethRees that would make sense in a longer loop, for example where `i` is used more than once, but in such a short one I think it's a moot point.

Comment: @jonrsharpe In my solution, what exactly is reduce technique? calling accumulate() in thos two functions product_using_accumulate() and summation_using_accumulate()?

Comment: @overexchange what? [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) is a built-in Python function that does exactly what your `accumulate` function is supposed to do, but with slightly different parameters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe what is the advantage of learning/writing such crytic syntax? `reduce(combiner, (f(i+1) for i in range(n)), start)`?  `total = combiner(total, f(i+1))` looks more readable

Comment: @jonrsharpe why the naming conventions change language to language? in python `lowercase_with_underscores`, In java `thisVar`

Comment: @overexchange to answer your first question - because it allows me to implement the function in a single line, relying on well-optimised, built-in Python (probably C) code for the tricky stuff. To the second - because different languages have different conventions according to the tastes of key developers (in Python's case, Guido van Rossum).

Comment: @jonrsharpe  Is this solution talking about principle "Don't Repeat Yourself(DRY)"?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Without/With using accumulate(), Can we also say that there is Functional abstraction of How summation() and product() is being performed?

Comment: @overexchange well, does it reduce repetition? Has it abstracted functionality?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Does it reduce repetition? Yes it did. Has it abstracted functionality? Yes it did, Because the user of summation_using_accumulate() does not bother, if its logic is implemented by again calling accumulate() internally or using while loop? That is why i say, functionality is abstracted. correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @overexchange I think you've answered your own questions, then!

Comment: @jonrsharpe Do we also see Data abstraction in this solution? Because i did not understand the meaning of Data abstraction(non-theoretical). Do we have any such context in this solution?

Comment: @overexchange perhaps you should talk to your teacher - this is well off-topic for CodeReview

Answer (score 5):

1. If a homework problem starts with the words "Show that", I would expect the answer to contain a *proof* (or at least an *argument*), not just an implementation.
2. You've misunderstood the problem statement. It says that `start` "specifies what *value* to use to start the accumulation", but in your implementation, `start` is the *index* of the first item in the sequence to contribute to the accumulation. Both of the test cases have `start=1` and `f(1)=1` so they are incapable of detecting your mistake.
3. Your implementations of `summation_using_accumulate` and `product_using_accumulate` do not actually use `accumulate`!

Comment: for your point, `Your implementations of summation_using_accumulate and product_using_accumulate do not actually use accumulate!` please help me understand, where was this point told in the question?

Comment: for your second point, i edited my query, do u think it make sense now? and i tested with different start values

Comment: @overexchange the `start` argument to `accumulate` for adding should be `0`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but question says: `a start value that specifies what base value to use to start the accumulation.` from this what i understand is, what is the start value of the sequence whose last term in sequence is n. did i mis-understand? so in one example i gave argument as 1 and another example i gave argument as 3

Comment: @overexchange yes, you misunderstood - that's the value to *start the accumulation*, not *to start the sequence*. It should be `total = start` not `total = f(start)`. The sequence always starts at `f(1)`.