# Summation and product functions using functional paradigm

Tags: python, python-3.x, functional-programming

Below is the problem:

> Show that both summation and product are instances of a more general function, called accumulate, with the following signature:
>
> ```
> def accumulate(combiner, start, n, term):
>     """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```
>
> Accumulate takes as arguments the same arguments term and n as summation and product, together with a combiner function (of two arguments) that specifies how the current term is to be combined with the accumulation of the preceding terms and a start value that specifies what base value to use to start the accumulation. Implement accumulate and show how summation and product can both be defined as simple calls to accumulate:
>
> ```
> def summation_using_accumulate(n, term):
>     """An implementation of summation using accumulate.
>
>     >>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
>     30
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
>
> def product_using_accumulate(n, term):
>     """An implementation of product using accumulate.
>
>     >>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
>     576
>     """
>     "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***"
> ```

For which, solution is mentioned below:

```
from operator import add
from operator import mul

def square(x):
    """ Retrun x squared"""
    return x * x


def accumulate(combiner, start, n, term):
    """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
    if n == 0:
        return start
    else:
        start = combiner(term(n), start)
        return accumulate(combiner, start, n-1, term)

def summation_using_accumulate(n, term):
    """An implementation of summation using accumulate.

    >>> summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
    30
    """
    assert n >= 0
    return accumulate(add, 0, n, term)



def product_using_accumulate(n, term):
    """An implementation of product using accumulate.

    >>> product_using_accumulate(4, square)
    576
    """
    assert n > 0
    return  accumulate(mul, 1, n, term)    

result =  summation_using_accumulate(4, square)
print(result)
result = product_using_accumulate(3, square)
print(result)
```

Please let me know if this program can be improved further using functional paradigm and the DRY principle.

Comment: See the [previous time this was asked](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/56744/11728) by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `start` parameter of `accumulate` is a bit misleading.
My first thought was that `start` is the first element of the sequence,
but it's an accumulated value.
A more common name is `acc` or `accum`.

Reassigning function parameter is considered a bad practice, 
in any language as far as I remember.
It's basically reusing an input variable for one additional purpose.
`start` is an input to your function,
but when you reassign it, it becomes something else:
instead of being just the input,
now it carries the result of a calculation.
When you look at your function body,
the variable `start` is sometimes the input, 
sometimes the result of a local calculation.
This duality in purpose can be confusing and can lead to errors.
It's cleaner to assign the mutated value to a completely new local variable.

In this version, `acc` always has the same value,
there can be no confusion and misuse, it's perfectly clear:

```
def accumulate(combiner, acc, n, term):
    """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
    if n == 0:
        return acc
    else:
        next_acc = combiner(term(n), acc)
        return accumulate(combiner, next_acc, n-1, term)
```

The benefit may not be obvious in this simple function,
but I hope you see the truth in the principle of not reusing parameter variables.
In a longer, more complicated function the benefits would become more clear.

In languages that have out-parameters,
re-assignment of parameters forces me to double-check the signature.
Although Python doesn't have out-parameters,
I still review code like this with suspicion,
in case the author may have mistakenly believed that the re-assigned value will produce a side effect outside the function.
This may sound a bit paranoid, but I've seen this kind of thing happen more than once.
By not re-assigning parameters,
all suspicions are cleared, and the code is easier to review.

For the record, I was tempted to suggest to drop the `else` clause there,
to simplify to:

```
def accumulate(combiner, acc, n, term):
    """Return the result of combining the first n terms in a sequence."""
    if n == 0:
        return acc
    next_acc = combiner(term(n), acc)
    return accumulate(combiner, next_acc, n-1, term)
```

But then, most functional languages return the last evaluation,
and explicit `return` statements are not recommended,
which makes `if-else` necessary.
For example the Scala solution would look something like this:

```
def accumulate(combiner, acc, n, term): Int = {
    if (n == 0) {
        acc
    } else {
        val nextAcc = combiner(term(n), acc)
        accumulate(combiner, nextAcc, n-1, term)
    }
}
```

So using the explicit `else` clause is closer to the spirit of functional programming, so I'd leave that as you did.

Comment: For your point: `when you reassign it, it becomes something else, which can be confusing and can lead to errors.` What kind of errors does this re-assignment can lead to? This is the most vague part for me which is yet to be understood.  I learnt that re-assignment is against the spirit of FP. why? am not sure. Please help me on this!!!

Comment: Hi @overexchange, I rephrased that part, and added a new paragraph about an additional concern of misunderstood out-parameters. Let me know if any of this is still not yet clear.

Comment: @janos Yes, I agree that, `Reassigning function parameter is considered a bad practice` and further reasons make sense. But If we have locally scoped object `count` in the [solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79337/37254) given by OP, `count` is re-assigned  to carry the result of a calculation. What is the rationale behind re-assignment of locally scoped objects pointed by `count`, being considered a bad practice in FP? Because `count` holds the meaning of purpose it is introduced for. In addition reassignment of `count`is an abstraction from the user who is using that function.

Comment: @overexchange for the record, my argument against reusing function parameters for local mutations is for all languages, not only FP. About the `count` variable in the question you linked, the variable is local, not a function parameter, so mutating it with `+=` is fine. Although FP prefers no mutations, in this case, since the variable is local, and as such there's no danger of concurrent access by multiple threads, I think the mutation is acceptable.

Comment: Wrt the point `Although Python doesn't have out-parameters` Is the second parameter of codesnippet in this [solution](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/80027/37254) `def computeSequence(n, listOfSequence):` not an out-param? I did not get you when you say, Python does not have out-parameters.

Comment: An input parameter that gets mutated for the purpose of storing the output is indeed sometimes loosely called output parameter. My point was about *true* out parameters, where the parameter variable can be reassigned, and the new value will be visible in the caller. Python doesn't have this kind of out parameters. Languages that do have this kind of out parameter usually use the `out` keyword in the method signature.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me, except this line:

```
start = combiner(term(n), start)
```

Reassigning variables is considered improper in functional programming.

Comment: Is it? The "improper" thing is mutating; rebinding is normally fine, albeit is just shadowing in most functional languages.

Comment: So, Can you suggest me with alternate solution?

Comment: @Veedrac Whether you re-bind or mutate, python creates a new object and get refers by name `start`. So every object in the above program has a single state in its life time.

Comment: @overexchange I can't tell whether you're agreeing with me or not. Anyway, I wrote [an example in OCaml](https://gist.github.com/Veedrac/eea4542126497e9e3817) to make it obvious what I mean.

Comment: @Veedrac The shadowing in your OCaml is OK, since `let` makes a new scope, and the rebinding has no side-effect outside that scope. In `start = combiner(term(n), start)`, however, no new scope is created; the new value of `start` is henceforth effective throughout the function's stack frame. That side-effect is why I think it is against the spirit of functional programming. Since Python doesn't offer a better scoping mechanism than the function, my recommendation is to either choose a different variable name or just write `accumulate(combiner, combiner(term(n), start), n-1, term)` inline.